# Why do games set FPS target rates in intervals of 30?

Tags: game-engine, game-physics, frame-rate

I've been working on a simple game in JS using canvas, and I've been looping a certain function every 16 milliseconds (1000/60 = 16.67) and it works fine, but I was just wondering why games don't aim for 25/50/100 FPS instead of 30/60/120 since they can divide into 1 (second) without anything left over?

It may be that what I'm doing has nothing to do with FPS, and real games work in a completely different way. If that's the case I would love to be proven wrong and be pointed in the right direction

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think games aim for 30/60/120? 60 or 120 are common refresh rates for monitors, so that's a "natural" refresh rate, but no recent computer monitor has only 30 Hz.

Comment: @PMF: A lot of games lock themselves to 30fps, especially console games. Granted, the OP does seem to be referring to browser game development here...

Comment: Ok, if to be run on an old TV (they have 30 FPS for NTSC, 25 for PAL), this makes sense, but no more for computer monitors.

Comment: If a monitor has a refresh rate of 60fps and the game runs at 30 fps, it  has two frames to do its drawing work and can then smoothly change the frame buffer to display what it has been drawing for the last two frames. If it were to lock at 25fps, this would not conveniently map to the screen refresh rate.